# How to fetch either the total value or SUM(value) in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

Within MS Access I have connected to an external Oracle database table that a have read only access. That table tracks the production process of articles (prodnr). An article might be produced in one run or several runs until the targeted amount is complete.

How to fetch from that table either the complete AMOUNT (completekz = 1) or SUM(AMOUNT) (only completekz = 0 entries ).

```
PRODNR COMPLETEKZ BACOMPLETEKZ     AMOUNT
------ ---------- ------------ ----------
   ...            ...                 ...
    16 0          partial             500
    16 0          partial           20000
    16 0          partial            8000
    16 1          complete          40000
    17 1          complete            100
    18 0          partial           10000
    18 0          partial            1500
    19 1          complete          35000
   ...            ...                 ...
```

Here is my query that returns all four rows. I can't seemt to find the correct way.

```
SELECT 
prodnr,
completekz,
bacompletekz,
IIF ( ((SELECT MAX(sub1.completekz) FROM aforueck AS sub1 WHERE sub1.prodnr = '16') = '1'),
  amount,
  '-1'
) AS Test
FROM aforueck
WHERE prodnr = '16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider

this

`SELECT Q1.prodnr, Sum(IIf(([completekz]=1 And [MaxComp]=1) Or ([completekz]=0 And [MaxComp]=0),[Amount],0)) AS SumAmt
FROM (SELECT aforueck.prodnr, aforueck.completekz, aforueck.bacompletekz, aforueck.amount, DMax("Completekz","aforueck","Prodnr='" & [prodnr] & "'") AS MaxComp
FROM aforueck) AS Q1
GROUP BY prodnr;`

or

`SELECT aforueck.prodnr, Sum(IIf(([completekz]=1 And [MaxComp]=1) Or ([completekz]=0 And [MaxComp]=0),[Amount],0)) AS SumAmt
FROM (SELECT aforueck.PRODNR, Max(aforueck.COMPLETEKZ) AS MaxComp FROM aforueck GROUP BY aforueck.PRODNR) AS Q1 
INNER JOIN aforueck ON Q1.PRODNR = aforueck.PRODNR
GROUP BY aforueck.prodnr;`

Both return:
`+--------+--------+
| prodnr | SumAmt |
+--------+--------+
|     16 |  40000 |
|     17 |    100 |
|     18 |  11500 |
|     19 |  35000 |
+--------+--------+`

This fits the description of "complete AMOUNT (completekz = 1) or SUM(AMOUNT) (only completekz = 0 entries )". If that is not desired output, provide an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately neither query returns the desired value and I am not able to read from the statements why that is. The target table contains many entries having idential prodnr but either query returns completely different rows not containing any match. Mabe my approach is wrong. Mabe I should always fetch the last entry for a group of a prodnr. But this leads me back to the same question. How would the appropriate query look like? I improved my entry post to explain the situation clearer.

Comment: You provided more examples of raw data but still say 'returns all four rows'. Not really clearer. See my revised answer.

Comment: In fact I wasn't sure whether my problem was clear since I receive strange results from my datasource, but your returned data is what I expect. For some reason it does not return from my data source what I expect, which is why I wonder whether my approach to fetch the desired row was the right or another approach (always pick the last row for a prodnr) might be the better solution. I am not sure whether I may ask almost the same question as a new question or if I should ask here how to fetch always the last row for a prodnr. Don't wanna get downvoted for nothing. What do you suggest?

Comment: If a prodnr has only '0 partial' records, which one would be the 'last' row? Regardless of how they appear in table, records have no established order, not like rows in an Excel spreadsheet.